# PHP image purging exceeds maximum execution time

Tags: php, curl

I am cleaning up an old PHP application on a LAMP-stack.
Everything seems to work as normal, but a purging function within a Request-library times out every time. The code takes in an image URI.

I get a timeout-error after 30 seconds like this:
`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /<pathToFolder>/Tools/Request.php on line 133`, which is the line `if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {`.
There is nothing wrong with the image URI. I have also tried to max the execution time to 360 seconds, but it still fails. Infinite loop, maybe? If so, why?

Anyone have any idea?

```
public static function purge($uri = '') {
    if ($uri == '') {
        throw new Exception('Uri is not set');
    }

    $chVarnish01 = curl_init($uri);
    $chVarnish02 = curl_init($uri);
    $chVarnish03 = curl_init($uri);

    curl_setopt_array($chVarnish01, array(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PURGE', CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('varnish: 01')));
    curl_setopt_array($chVarnish02, array(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PURGE', CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('varnish: 02')));
    curl_setopt_array($chVarnish03, array(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PURGE', CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('varnish: 03')));

    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $chVarnish01);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $chVarnish02);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $chVarnish03);

    $active = null;
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
        if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }

    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chVarnish01);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chVarnish02);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chVarnish03);
    curl_multi_close($mh);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Some servers only respond to reqeust made from webbrowsers, to eliminate traffictheft. Try to add a header with a faked User-Agent to your curl options with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'); for instance. At least this helped me with a similar problem I had with fetching favicons from urls in a small project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work :(.